# local state management for graphql vue apollo

Tags: graphql, vue-apollo, apollo-cache-inmemory

I am trying to make local state management with vue apollo, but even after [following the docs](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/local-state.html) I am getting no result. There is no error in the console so I am not sure what is wrong.

Here is my setup:

```
// main.js file the initializing part

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    errorLink,
    authMiddleware,
    link,
  ]),
  cache,
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  connectToDevTools: true,
});
```

```
// resolvers file

import gql from 'graphql-tag';

import { todoItemsQuery } from './task.queries';

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Item {
    id: ID!
    text: String!
    done: Boolean!
  }

  type Mutation {
    changeItem(id: ID!): Boolean
    deleteItem(id: ID!): Boolean
    addItem(text: String!): Item
  }
`;


export const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    checkItem: (_, { id }, { cache }) => {
      const data = cache.readQuery({ query: todoItemsQuery });

      console.log('data res', data);
      const currentItem = data.todoItems.find(item => item.id === id);
      currentItem.done = !currentItem.done;
      cache.writeQuery({ query: todoItemsQuery, data });
      return currentItem.done;
    },
  },
};
```

```
//queries file

import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const todoItemsQuery = gql`
  {
    todoItems @client {
      id
      text
      done
    }
  }
`;

export const checkItemMutation = gql`
  mutation($id: ID!) {
    checkItem(id: $id) @client
  }
`;
```

```
// component where I call it

  apollo: {
    todoItems: {
      query: todoItemsQuery
    }
  },

    checkItem(id) {
      this.$apollo
        .mutate({
          mutation: checkItemMutation,
          variables: { id }
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log("CACHE", data);
        });
    },
```

I get empty todoItems, no errors.

Please let me know what am I missing, I am not grasping some concept I think, and if there is a way to use vuex with apollo then I can do that too.

Answer (score 2):

*Foreword: I'm not an Apollo specialist, just starting to use it.*

Just in case, these thoughts may help you. If they don't, well, I'm sorry.

In main.js: Apollo documentation provides a slightly different set up when using Apollo Boost (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state/#with-apollo-boost). Just in case, this is how I have set up my implementation so far.

```
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

Vue.use(VueApollo)
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  //...whatever you may already have,
  clientState: {
    // "defaults" is your initial state - if empty, I think it might error out when your app launches but is not hydrated yet.
    defaults: {
      todoItems: [],
    }
    cache,
    typeDefs: {...yourTypeDefs},
    resolvers: {...yourResolvers},
  },
});
const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
});
```

In your typeDefs: I can not see a Query Type for your todoItems:

```
type Query {
  todoItemsQuery: [Item]
}
```

In your component: my own implementation was not working until I added an update method to the apollo request:

```
apollo: {
  todoItems: {
    query: todoItemsQuery,
    update: data => data.todoItems
  }
},
```